# Parent array is not allowed JOI npm library

Tags: node.js, json, joi

Hi im using Joi for validating JSON objects on a simple API, my validation schema is :

```
let holidays = Joi.object().keys({
    day: Joi.number().required(),
    month: Joi.number().required(),
    description: Joi.string().required()
})

const countryValidateSchema = Joi.object().keys({
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    holidays: Joi.array().items(holidays),
    states: Joi.array().required().items(Joi.string())
});
```

And I validate it like this when a new country is added:

```
function newCountry(req, res) {
    //TODO validate
    var newCountry = new Country(req.body);

    const result = Joi.validate(newCountry, validate.countryValidateSchema);
    const { value, error } = result; 
    const valid = error == null; 

    if (!valid) { 
      res.status(422).json({ 
        message: result, 
        data: newCountry 
      }) 
    } else { 
        //Store on DB
        newCountry.save((err,country) =>{
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }else{
                res.status(201).json({message: "Country successfully added!", country})
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I try to add a new country with this JSON it throws the error:
***ParentArray is not allowed***

```
{
    "name": "TestCountry",
    "holidays": [
        {
            "day": 1,
            "month": 2,
            "description": "test"
        }
    ],
    "states": [
         "test1",
         "test2",
         "test3",
         "test34"
        ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

He is the full error trace

```
{
    "message": {
        "error": {
            "isJoi": true,
            "name": "ValidationError",
            "details": [
                {
                    "message": "\"__parentArray\" is not allowed",
                    "path": [
                        "holidays",
                        0,
                        "__parentArray"
                    ],
                    "type": "object.allowUnknown",
                    "context": {
                        "child": "__parentArray",
                        "value": [
                            {
                                "_id": "5daf5e657f19e312de414613",
                                "day": 1,
                                "month": 2,
                                "description": "test"
                            }
                        ],
                        "key": "__parentArray",
                        "label": "__parentArray"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "message": "\"__index\" is not allowed",
                    "path": [
                        "holidays",
                        0,
                        "__index"
                    ],
                    "type": "object.allowUnknown",
                    "context": {
                        "child": "__index",
                        "value": 0,
                        "key": "__index",
                        "label": "__index"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "message": "\"$isDocumentArrayElement\" is not allowed",
                    "path": [
                        "holidays",
                        0,
                        "$isDocumentArrayElement"
                    ],
                    "type": "object.allowUnknown",
                    "context": {
                        "child": "$isDocumentArrayElement",
                        "value": true,
                        "key": "$isDocumentArrayElement",
                        "label": "$isDocumentArrayElement"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "message": "\"$__\" is not allowed",
                    "path": [
                        "holidays",
                        0,
                        "$__"
                    ],
                    "type": "object.allowUnknown",
                    "context": {
                        "child": "$__",
                        "value": {
                            "strictMode": true,
                            "getters": {},
                            "_id": "5daf5e657f19e312de414613",
                            "wasPopulated": false,
                            "activePaths": {
                                "paths": {
                                    "description": "modify",
                                    "month": "modify",
                                    "day": "modify",
                                    "_id": "default"
                                },
                                "states": {
                                    "ignore": {},
                                    "default": {
                                        "_id": true
                                    },
                                    "init": {},
                                    "modify": {
                                        "day": true,
                                        "month": true,
                                        "description": true
                                    },
                                    "require": {}
                                },
                                "stateNames": [
                                    "require",
                                    "modify",
                                    "init",
                                    "default",
                                    "ignore"
                                ]
                            },
                            "pathsToScopes": {},
                            "cachedRequired": {},
                            "session": null,
                            "$setCalled": {},
                            "ownerDocument": {
                                "states": [
                                    "test1",
                                    "test2",
                                    "test3",
                                    "test34"
                                ],
                                "_id": "5daf5e657f19e312de414612",
                                "name": "TestCountry",
                                "holidays": [
                                    {
                                        "_id": "5daf5e657f19e312de414613",
                                        "day": 1,
                                        "month": 2,
                                        "description": "test"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "fullPath": "holidays",
                            "emitter": {
                                "_events": {},
                                "_eventsCount": 2,
                                "_maxListeners": 0
                            },
                            "$options": {}
                        },
                        "key": "$__",
                        "label": "$__"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "message": "\"isNew\" is not allowed",
                    "path": [
                        "holidays",
                        0,
                        "isNew"
                    ],
                    "type": "object.allowUnknown",
                    "context": {
                        "child": "isNew",
                        "value": true,
                        "key": "isNew",
                        "label": "isNew"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "message": "\"errors\" is not allowed",
                    "path": [
                        "holidays",
                        0,
                        "errors"
                    ],
                    "type": "object.allowUnknown",
                    "context": {
                        "child": "errors",
                        "key": "errors",
                        "label": "errors"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "message": "\"_doc\" is not allowed",
                    "path": [
                        "holidays",
                        0,
                        "_doc"
                    ],
                    "type": "object.allowUnknown",
                    "context": {
                        "child": "_doc",
                        "value": {
                            "_id": "5daf5e657f19e312de414613",
                            "day": 1,
                            "month": 2,
                            "description": "test"
                        },
                        "key": "_doc",
                        "label": "_doc"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "message": "\"$locals\" is not allowed",
                    "path": [
                        "holidays",
                        0,
                        "$locals"
                    ],
                    "type": "object.allowUnknown",
                    "context": {
                        "child": "$locals",
                        "value": {},
                        "key": "$locals",
                        "label": "$locals"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "_object": {
                "states": [
                    "test1",
                    "test2",
                    "test3",
                    "test34"
                ],
                "_id": "5daf5e657f19e312de414612",
                "name": "TestCountry",
                "holidays": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5daf5e657f19e312de414613",
                        "day": 1,
                        "month": 2,
                        "description": "test"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "value": {
            "states": [
                "test1",
                "test2",
                "test3",
                "test34"
            ],
            "_id": "5daf5e657f19e312de414612",
            "name": "TestCountry",
            "holidays": [
                {
                    "_id": "5daf5e657f19e312de414613",
                    "day": 1,
                    "month": 2,
                    "description": "test"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "states": [
            "test1",
            "test2",
            "test3",
            "test34"
        ],
        "_id": "5daf5e657f19e312de414612",
        "name": "TestCountry",
        "holidays": [
            {
                "_id": "5daf5e657f19e312de414613",
                "day": 1,
                "month": 2,
                "description": "test"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I was validating an Country object instead of the json body. So the solution is to change

```
var newCountry = new Country(req.body);
```

to

```
var newCountry = req.body;
```